# Apply criteria from one table against each row in another table to generate a list of matches

Tags: r, function, loops, vector

I have 2 tables of data.  1 table has a list of start and end date ranges.  The other table a list of students with their class and start dates.  For each of the date ranges, I'm trying to list the students who have a start date in that range.

Range Data

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 10/1/2023 | 12/31/2023 |
| 7/1/2023 | 9/30/2023 |
| 4/1/2023 | 6/30/2023 |
| 1/1/2023 | 3/31/2023 |

Student

| Learner | Course | Start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 11/5/23 |
| 1 | Math | 7/10/23 |
| 2 | English | 7/25/23 |
| 2 | Math | 5/15/23 |
| 3 | Science | 4/25/23 |
| 3 | Math | 7/25/23 |
| 3 | English | 11/15/23 |
| 4 | Science | 11/5/23 |
| 4 | Math | 1/5/23 |

If I only have a single date range to filter against, I can do this using filter() to filter by start dates, but I have a dozen different ranges and don't want to run in manually for each range.  My intended outcome is a list of ranges with the students having a class in that range

| Start | End | Learner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2023 | 12/31/2023 | 1 |
| 10/1/2023 | 12/31/2023 | 3 |
| 10/1/2023 | 12/31/2023 | 4 |
| 7/1/2023 | 9/30/2023 | 1 |
| 7/1/2023 | 9/30/2023 | 2 |
| 7/1/2023 | 9/30/2023 | 3 |
| 4/1/2023 | 6/30/2023 | 2 |
| 4/1/2023 | 6/30/2023 | 3 |
| 1/1/2023 | 3/31/2023 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

```
mutate(df1, across(everything(), mdy)) %>%
   right_join(mutate(df2, Start = mdy(Start)), 
             by = join_by(Start <= Start , End>Start), 
             suffix = c('', '_y'))%>%
   select(-Start_y, -Course)

       Start        End Learner
1 2023-10-01 2023-12-31       1
2 2023-10-01 2023-12-31       3
3 2023-10-01 2023-12-31       4
4 2023-07-01 2023-09-30       1
5 2023-07-01 2023-09-30       2
6 2023-07-01 2023-09-30       3
7 2023-04-01 2023-06-30       2
8 2023-04-01 2023-06-30       3
9 2023-01-01 2023-03-31       4
```

Answer (score 0):

A **base R** approach. The tricky part here is not finding the matches but getting the desired format of repeated dates in separate rows.

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
  apply(ranges, 1, \(x) 
    t(sapply(which(
      as.Date(student$Start, "%m/%d/%y") >= as.Date(x["Start"], "%m/%d/%Y") & 
      as.Date(student$Start, "%m/%d/%y") <= as.Date(x["End"], "%m/%d/%Y")), \(y)
        c(x, Learner=student$Learner[y]))))))
      Start        End Learner
1 10/1/2023 12/31/2023       1
2 10/1/2023 12/31/2023       3
3 10/1/2023 12/31/2023       4
4  7/1/2023  9/30/2023       1
5  7/1/2023  9/30/2023       2
6  7/1/2023  9/30/2023       3
7  4/1/2023  6/30/2023       2
8  4/1/2023  6/30/2023       3
9  1/1/2023  3/31/2023       4
```

Note: Be careful with years in dates. 2-digits years need `%y`, 4-digit years `%Y`.

##### Data

```
ranges <- structure(list(Start = c("10/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "4/1/2023", 
"1/1/2023"), End = c("12/31/2023", "9/30/2023", "6/30/2023", 
"3/31/2023")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

student <- structure(list(Learner = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L
), Course = c("English", "Math", "English", "Math", "Science", 
"Math", "English", "Science", "Math"), Start = c("11/5/23", "7/10/23", 
"7/25/23", "5/15/23", "4/25/23", "7/25/23", "11/15/23", "11/5/23", 
"1/5/23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function `f` that compares a range with a student's start date and loop over all combinations. In such double-`for`-loop situations we may use `outer` which gives a boolean matrix where we want `max.col`. Finally `merge`.

First however, care for your strange date formats and rename student's Start to Start_stud to have unique column names.

```
> ranges[] <- lapply(ranges, as.Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
> student <- transform(student, Start_stud=as.Date(student$Start, '%m/%d/%y'), Start=NULL)
> f <- \(x, y) student$Start[x] >= ranges[y, 1] & student$Start[x] <= ranges[y, 2]
> student$id <- max.col(outer(seq_len(nrow(student)), seq_len(nrow(ranges)), f))
> merge(ranges, student, by.x=0, by.y='id') |> {\(.) .[order(.[, 2]), -1]}()
       Start        End Learner  Course Start_stud
9 2023-01-01 2023-03-31       4    Math 2023-01-05
7 2023-04-01 2023-06-30       3 Science 2023-04-25
8 2023-04-01 2023-06-30       2    Math 2023-05-15
4 2023-07-01 2023-09-30       1    Math 2023-07-10
5 2023-07-01 2023-09-30       3    Math 2023-07-25
6 2023-07-01 2023-09-30       2 English 2023-07-25
1 2023-10-01 2023-12-31       1 English 2023-11-05
2 2023-10-01 2023-12-31       3 English 2023-11-15
3 2023-10-01 2023-12-31       4 Science 2023-11-05
```

If you really want just the first three columns, you can pipe in another `|> subset(select=1:3)`.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(ranges)
structure(list(Start = c("10/1/2023", "7/1/2023", "4/1/2023", 
"1/1/2023"), End = c("12/31/2023", "9/30/2023", "6/30/2023", 
"3/31/2023")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
> dput(student)
structure(list(Learner = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L
), Course = c("English", "Math", "English", "Math", "Science", 
"Math", "English", "Science", "Math"), Start = c("11/5/23", "7/10/23", 
"7/25/23", "5/15/23", "4/25/23", "7/25/23", "11/15/23", "11/5/23", 
"1/5/23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```